# How to write this query in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

The query is `SELECT country, count(*) as count FROM visitors GROUP BY country ORDER BY count DESC`. How to write with Visitor model eloquently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Visitor::query()->groupBy('country')->orderByDesc('count')->select('country' ,DB::raw('COUNT(1) as count'))->get()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try somthing like this

```php
Visitor::select('country')
     ->withCount('id')
     ->groupBy('country')
     ->latest()
     ->get()
```

Comment: Its giving an exception: Call to undefined method App\Visitor::*()

Comment: Change it to 'id' instead